# invalid input syntax for integer: "E00001"-PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I'm trying to implement the following code in PostgreSQL and the error below:

```
select distinct *
from (
    select distinct
        vendor,lag(cast(vendor as bigint)) over (order by cast(vendor as bigint)) Previous_Vendor,
        (cast(vendor as bigint) - lag(cast(vendor as bigint)) over (order by cast(vendor as bigint))-1) Gaps_in_sequence
    from vendor_view 
    where
        vendor not like $$%A%$$ and
        vendor not like $$%c%$$ and
        vendor is not null and
        vendor not like '%-%' and
        vendor not like 'T%'
) a 
where Gaps_in_sequence > 0 and Previous_vendor is not null order by vendor;

ERROR:
invalid input syntax for integer: "E00001"
```

What does this mean? How should I remove this? Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: `E00001` is not an integer ... rather a `string`

Comment: how to correct this then?